# How to destroy and reinitialize angular directive -- on window resize?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've tried invoking the directive below again on   $(window).resize, and adding scope.$digest to it, but the directive does not respond.

I'm attempting to load responsive width and height (which are properties of scope.viewport and scope.boundary) to the options: boundary / viewport width and height -- on resize.

What is the proper way to accomplish this?

```
angular.module('ngCroppie', []).directive('ngCroppie', [
  function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope:{
          src: '=',
          viewport: '=',
          boundry: '=',
          type: '@',
          zoom: '@',
          mousezoom: '@',
          update: '=',
          ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

                // defaults
                if(scope.viewport == undefined){
                  scope.viewport = {w: null, h: null}
                }

                if(scope.boundry == undefined){
                  scope.boundry = {w: null, h: null}
                }

                // catches
                scope.viewport.w = (scope.viewport.w != undefined) ? scope.viewport.w : 300;
                scope.viewport.h = (scope.viewport.h != undefined) ? scope.viewport.h : 300;
                scope.boundry.w = (scope.boundry.w != undefined) ? scope.boundry.w : 400;
                scope.boundry.h = (scope.boundry.h != undefined) ? scope.boundry.h : 400;

                // viewport cannot be larger than the boundaries
                if(scope.viewport.w > scope.boundry.w){ scope.viewport.w = scope.boundry.w }
                if(scope.viewport.h > scope.boundry.h){ scope.viewport.h = scope.boundry.h }

                // convert string to Boolean
                var zoom = (scope.zoom === "true"),
                    mouseZoom = (scope.mousezoom === "true");

                // define options
                var options =  {
                    viewport: {
                      width: scope.viewport.w,
                      height: scope.viewport.h,
                      type: scope.type || 'square'
                    },
                    boundary: {
                      width: scope.boundry.w,
                      height: scope.boundry.h
                    },
                    showZoom: zoom,
                    mouseWheelZoom: mouseZoom,
                }

                if (scope.update != undefined){
                  options.update = scope.update
                }

                // create new croppie and settime for updates
                var c = new Croppie(elem[0], options);
                var intervalID = window.setInterval(function(){
                  c.result('canvas').then(function(img){
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                      scope.ngModel = img
                    })
                  })
                }, 250);

                scope.$on("$destroy",
                    function( event ) {
                        clearInterval(intervalID);
                    }
                );

                // respond to changes in src
                scope.$watch('src', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    if(scope.src != undefined){
                          c.bind(scope.src);
                          c.result('canvas').then(function(img){
                            scope.$apply(function(){
                              scope.ngModel = img
                            })
                          })
                    }
              })


        }

    };
  }
]);
```

---

Here's my updated code. Now, my problem is that it keeps making a new image (that is correctly resized). I cannot figure out how to delete the initial image which needs to be replaced:

```
function croppieJs (){ !function(t,e){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["exports","b"],e):"object"==typeof exports&&"string"!=typeof exports.nodeName?e(exports,require("b")):e(t.commonJsStrict={},t.b)}(this,function(t,e){function n(t){if(t in j)return t;for(var e=t[0].toUpperCase()+t.slice(1),n=X.length;n--;)if(t=X[n]+e,t in j)return t}function r(t){t=t||{};for(var e=1;e<arguments.length;e++){var n=arguments[e];if(n)for(var o in n)n.hasOwnProperty(o)&&("object"==typeof n[o]?t[o]=r({},n[o]):t[o]=n[o])}return t}function o(t,e,n){var r;return function(){var o=this,i=arguments,s=function(){r=null,n||t.apply(o,i)},a=n&&!r;clearTimeout(r),r=setTimeout(s,e),a&&t.apply(o,i)}}function i(t){if("createEvent"in document){var e=document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");e.initEvent("change",!1,!0),t.dispatchEvent(e)}else t.fireEvent("onchange")}function s(t,e,n){if("string"==typeof e){var r=e;e={},e[r]=n}for(var o in e)t.style[o]=e[o]}function a(t){var e=t.points,n=document.createElement("div"),r=document.createElement("img"),o=e[2]-e[0],i=e[3]-e[1];return n.classList.add("croppie-result"),n.appendChild(r),s(r,{left:-1*e[0]+"px",top:-1*e[1]+"px"}),r.src=t.url,s(n,{width:o+"px",height:i+"px"}),n}function u(t,e){var n=e.points,r=n[0],o=n[1],i=n[2]-n[0],s=n[3]-n[1],a=e.circle,u=document.createElement("canvas"),l=u.getContext("2d"),c=i,p=s;return e.outputWidth&&e.outputHeight&&(c=e.outputWidth,p=e.outputHeight),u.width=c,u.height=p,a&&(l.save(),l.beginPath(),l.arc(c/2,p/2,c/2,0,2*Math.PI,!0),l.closePath(),l.clip()),l.drawImage(t,r,o,i,s,0,0,c,p),u.toDataURL()}function l(t,e){var n,r=e||new Image;return n=new Promise(function(t,e){r.setAttribute("crossOrigin","anonymous"),r.onload=function(){setTimeout(function(){t(r)},1)}}),r.src=t,n}function c(){var t,e,n,r,o=this,i=["croppie-container"],a=o.options.viewport.type?"cr-vp-"+o.options.viewport.type:null;o.data={},o.elements={},t=o.elements.boundary=document.createElement("div"),n=o.elements.viewport=document.createElement("div"),e=o.elements.img=document.createElement("img"),r=o.elements.overlay=document.createElement("div"),t.classList.add("cr-boundary"),s(t,{width:o.options.boundary.width+o.options.metric,height:o.options.boundary.height+o.options.metric}),n.classList.add("cr-viewport"),a&&n.classList.add(a),s(n,{width:o.options.viewport.width+o.options.metric,height:o.options.viewport.height+o.options.metric}),e.classList.add("cr-image"),r.classList.add("cr-overlay"),o.element.appendChild(t),t.appendChild(e),t.appendChild(n),t.appendChild(r),o.element.classList.add(i),o.options.customClass&&o.element.classList.add(o.options.customClass),g.call(this),o.options.showZoom&&m.call(o)}function p(t){this.options.showZoom&&(this.elements.zoomer.value=E(t))}function m(){function t(){h.call(s),r=new I(s.elements.img),o=s.elements.viewport.getBoundingClientRect(),i=F.parse(s.elements.img)}function e(){d.call(s,{value:parseFloat(u.value),origin:r||new I(s.elements.img),viewportRect:o||s.elements.viewport.getBoundingClientRect(),transform:i||F.parse(s.elements.img)})}function n(n){var r=n.deltaY/-2e3,o=s._currentZoom+r;n.preventDefault(),t(),p.call(s,o),e()}var r,o,i,s=this,a=s.elements.zoomerWrap=document.createElement("div"),u=s.elements.zoomer=document.createElement("input");a.classList.add("cr-slider-wrap"),u.type="range",u.classList.add("cr-slider"),u.step="0.01",u.value=1,s.element.appendChild(a),a.appendChild(u),s._currentZoom=1,s.elements.zoomer.addEventListener("mousedown",t),s.elements.zoomer.addEventListener("touchstart",t),s.elements.zoomer.addEventListener("input",e),s.elements.zoomer.addEventListener("change",e),s.options.mouseWheelZoom&&(s.elements.boundary.addEventListener("mousewheel",n),s.elements.boundary.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll",n))}function d(t){var e=this,n=t.transform,r=t.viewportRect,o=t.origin;e._currentZoom=t.value,n.scale=e._currentZoom;var i=f.call(e,r),a=i.translate,u=i.origin;n.x>=a.maxX&&(o.x=u.minX,n.x=a.maxX),n.x<=a.minX&&(o.x=u.maxX,n.x=a.minX),n.y>=a.maxY&&(o.y=u.minY,n.y=a.maxY),n.y<=a.minY&&(o.y=u.maxY,n.y=a.minY);var l={};l[B]=n.toString(),l[M]=o.toString(),s(e.elements.img,l),O.call(e),y.call(e)}function f(t){var e=this,n=e._currentZoom,r=t.width,o=t.height,i=e.options.boundary.width/2,s=e.options.boundary.height/2,a=e._originalImageWidth,u=e._originalImageHeight,l=a*n,c=u*n,p=r/2,m=o/2,d=-1*(p/n-i),f=d-(l*(1/n)-r*(1/n)),h=-1*(m/n-s),g=h-(c*(1/n)-o*(1/n)),v=1/n*p,y=l*(1/n)-v,w=1/n*m,_=c*(1/n)-w;return{translate:{maxX:d,minX:f,maxY:h,minY:g},origin:{maxX:y,minX:v,maxY:_,minY:w}}}function h(){var t=this,e=t._currentZoom,n=t.elements.img.getBoundingClientRect(),r=t.elements.viewport.getBoundingClientRect(),o=F.parse(t.elements.img.style[B]),i=new I(t.elements.img),a=r.top-n.top+r.height/2,u=r.left-n.left+r.width/2,l={},c={};l.y=a/e,l.x=u/e,c.y=(l.y-i.y)*(1-e),c.x=(l.x-i.x)*(1-e),o.x-=c.x,o.y-=c.y;var p={};p[M]=l.x+"px "+l.y+"px",p[B]=o.toString(),s(t.elements.img,p)}function g(){function t(t){t.preventDefault(),c||(c=!0,r=t.pageX,o=t.pageY,transform=F.parse(l.elements.img),window.addEventListener("mousemove",e),window.addEventListener("touchmove",e),window.addEventListener("mouseup",n),window.addEventListener("touchend",n),document.body.style[Z]="none",u=l.elements.viewport.getBoundingClientRect())}function e(t){t.preventDefault();var e=t.pageX||t.touches[0].pageX,n=t.pageY||t.touches[0].pageY,c=e-r,m=n-o,d=l.elements.img.getBoundingClientRect(),f=transform.y+m,h=transform.x+c,g={};if("touchmove"==t.type&&t.touches.length>1){var y=t.touches[0],w=t.touches[1],_=Math.sqrt((y.pageX-w.pageX)*(y.pageX-w.pageX)+(y.pageY-w.pageY)*(y.pageY-w.pageY));a||(a=_/l._currentZoom);var x=_/a;return p.call(l,x),void i(l.elements.zoomer)}u.top>d.top+m&&u.bottom<d.bottom+m&&(transform.y=f),u.left>d.left+c&&u.right<d.right+c&&(transform.x=h),g[B]=transform.toString(),s(l.elements.img,g),v.call(l),o=n,r=e}function n(){c=!1,window.removeEventListener("mousemove",e),window.removeEventListener("touchmove",e),window.removeEventListener("mouseup",n),window.removeEventListener("touchend",n),document.body.style[Z]="",h.call(l),y.call(l),a=0}var r,o,a,u,l=this,c=!1;l.elements.overlay.addEventListener("mousedown",t),l.elements.overlay.addEventListener("touchstart",t)}function v(){var t=this,e=t.elements.boundary.getBoundingClientRect(),n=t.elements.img.getBoundingClientRect();s(t.elements.overlay,{width:n.width+"px",height:n.height+"px",top:n.top-e.top+"px",left:n.left-e.left+"px"})}function y(){var t=this;w.call(t)&&t.options.update.call(t,t.get())}function w(){return this.elements.img.offsetHeight>0&&this.elements.img.offsetWidth>0}function _(){var t,e,n,r,o,a=this,u=0,l=1.5,c=1,m={},d=a.elements.img,f=a.elements.zoomer,h=new F(0,0,c),g=new I,y=w.call(a);y&&!a.data.bound&&(a.data.bound=!0,m[B]=h.toString(),m[M]=g.toString(),s(d,m),t=d.getBoundingClientRect(),e=a.elements.viewport.getBoundingClientRect(),n=a.elements.boundary.getBoundingClientRect(),a._originalImageWidth=t.width,a._originalImageHeight=t.height,a.options.showZoom&&(r=e.width/t.width,o=e.height/t.height,u=Math.max(r,o),u>=l&&(l=u+1),f.min=E(u),f.max=E(l),c=Math.max(n.width/t.width,n.height/t.height),p.call(a,c),i(f)),a._currentZoom=h.scale=c,m[B]=h.toString(),s(d,m),a.data.points.length?x.call(a,a.data.points):b.call(a),v.call(a))}function x(t){if(4!=t.length)throw"Croppie - Invalid number of points supplied: "+t;var e=this,n=t[2]-t[0],r=e.elements.viewport.getBoundingClientRect(),o=e.elements.boundary.getBoundingClientRect(),i={left:r.left-o.left,top:r.top-o.top},a=r.width/n,u=t[1],l=t[0],c=-1*t[1]+i.top,m=-1*t[0]+i.left,d={};d[M]=l+"px "+u+"px",d[B]=new F(m,c,a).toString(),s(e.elements.img,d),p.call(e,a),e._currentZoom=a}function b(){var t=this,e=t.elements.img.getBoundingClientRect(),n=t.elements.viewport.getBoundingClientRect(),r=t.elements.boundary.getBoundingClientRect(),o=n.left-r.left,i=n.top-r.top,a=o-(e.width-n.width)/2,u=i-(e.height-n.height)/2,l=new F(a,u,t._currentZoom);s(t.elements.img,B,l.toString())}function C(t,e){var n,r=this,o=[];if("string"==typeof t)n=t,t={};else if(Array.isArray(t))o=t.slice();else{if("undefined"==typeof t&&r.data.url)return _.call(r),y.call(r),null;n=t.url,o=t.points||[]}r.data.bound=!1,r.data.url=n||r.data.url,r.data.points=(o||r.data.points).map(function(t){return parseFloat(t)});var i=l(n,r.elements.img);return i.then(function(){_.call(r),y.call(r),e&&e()}),i}function E(t){return parseFloat(t).toFixed(2)}function L(){var t=this,e=t.elements.img.getBoundingClientRect(),n=t.elements.viewport.getBoundingClientRect(),r=n.left-e.left,o=n.top-e.top,i=r+n.width,s=o+n.height,a=t._currentZoom;return(a===1/0||isNaN(a))&&(a=1),r=Math.max(0,r/a),o=Math.max(0,o/a),i=Math.max(0,i/a),s=Math.max(0,s/a),{points:[E(r),E(o),E(i),E(s)],zoom:a}}function S(t){var e,n,r=this,o=L.call(r),i=t||{type:"canvas",size:"viewport"},s="string"==typeof i?i:i.type,c=i.size||"viewport";return"viewport"===c&&(e=r.elements.viewport.getBoundingClientRect(),o.outputWidth=e.width,o.outputHeight=e.height),o.circle="circle"===r.options.viewport.type,o.url=r.data.url,n=new Promise(function(t,e){"canvas"===s?l(o.url).then(function(e){t(u(e,o))}):t(a(o))})}function A(){console.warn("Croppie.refresh() is deprecated.  Please use Croppie.bind() without any arguments instead.  refresh() will be removed in a later release."),_.call(this)}function R(){var t=this;t.element.removeChild(t.elements.boundary),t.options.showZoom&&t.element.removeChild(t.elements.zoomerWrap),delete t.elements}function Y(t,e){this.element=t,this.options=r({},Y.defaults,e),c.call(this)}"function"!=typeof Promise&&function(){"use strict";function t(t){return"function"==typeof t||"object"==typeof t&&null!==t}function e(t){return"function"==typeof t}function n(t){return"object"==typeof t&&null!==t}function r(t){W=t}function o(t){k=t}function i(){return function(){process.nextTick(c)}}function s(){return function(){T(c)}}function a(){var t=0,e=new Q(c),n=document.createTextNode("");return e.observe(n,{characterData:!0}),function(){n.data=t=++t%2}}function u(){var t=new MessageChannel;return t.port1.onmessage=c,function(){t.port2.postMessage(0)}}function l(){return function(){setTimeout(c,1)}}function c(){for(var t=0;q>t;t+=2){var e=G[t],n=G[t+1];e(n),G[t]=void 0,G[t+1]=void 0}q=0}function p(){try{var t=require,e=t("vertx");return T=e.runOnLoop||e.runOnContext,s()}catch(n){return l()}}function m(){}function d(){return new TypeError("You cannot resolve a promise with itself")}function f(){return new TypeError("A promises callback cannot return that same promise.")}function h(t){try{return t.then}catch(e){return et.error=e,et}}function g(t,e,n,r){try{t.call(e,n,r)}catch(o){return o}}function v(t,e,n){k(function(t){var r=!1,o=g(n,e,function(n){r||(r=!0,e!==n?_(t,n):b(t,n))},function(e){r||(r=!0,C(t,e))},"Settle: "+(t._label||" unknown promise"));!r&&o&&(r=!0,C(t,o))},t)}function y(t,e){e._state===$?b(t,e._result):e._state===tt?C(t,e._result):E(e,void 0,function(e){_(t,e)},function(e){C(t,e)})}function w(t,n){if(n.constructor===t.constructor)y(t,n);else{var r=h(n);r===et?C(t,et.error):void 0===r?b(t,n):e(r)?v(t,n,r):b(t,n)}}function _(e,n){e===n?C(e,d()):t(n)?w(e,n):b(e,n)}function x(t){t._onerror&&t._onerror(t._result),L(t)}function b(t,e){t._state===V&&(t._result=e,t._state=$,0!==t._subscribers.length&&k(L,t))}function C(t,e){t._state===V&&(t._state=tt,t._result=e,k(x,t))}function E(t,e,n,r){var o=t._subscribers,i=o.length;t._onerror=null,o[i]=e,o[i+$]=n,o[i+tt]=r,0===i&&t._state&&k(L,t)}function L(t){var e=t._subscribers,n=t._state;if(0!==e.length){for(var r,o,i=t._result,s=0;s<e.length;s+=3)r=e[s],o=e[s+n],r?R(n,r,o,i):o(i);t._subscribers.length=0}}function S(){this.error=null}function A(t,e){try{return t(e)}catch(n){return nt.error=n,nt}}function R(t,n,r,o){var i,s,a,u,l=e(r);if(l){if(i=A(r,o),i===nt?(u=!0,s=i.error,i=null):a=!0,n===i)return void C(n,f())}else i=o,a=!0;n._state!==V||(l&&a?_(n,i):u?C(n,s):t===$?b(n,i):t===tt&&C(n,i))}function Y(t,e){try{e(function(e){_(t,e)},function(e){C(t,e)})}catch(n){C(t,n)}}function M(t,e){var n=this;n._instanceConstructor=t,n.promise=new t(m),n._validateInput(e)?(n._input=e,n.length=e.length,n._remaining=e.length,n._init(),0===n.length?b(n.promise,n._result):(n.length=n.length||0,n._enumerate(),0===n._remaining&&b(n.promise,n._result))):C(n.promise,n._validationError())}function B(t){return new rt(this,t).promise}function Z(t){function e(t){_(o,t)}function n(t){C(o,t)}var r=this,o=new r(m);if(!H(t))return C(o,new TypeError("You must pass an array to race.")),o;for(var i=t.length,s=0;o._state===V&&i>s;s++)E(r.resolve(t[s]),void 0,e,n);return o}function X(t){var e=this;if(t&&"object"==typeof t&&t.constructor===e)return t;var n=new e(m);return _(n,t),n}function j(t){var e=this,n=new e(m);return C(n,t),n}function P(){throw new TypeError("You must pass a resolver function as the first argument to the promise constructor")}function z(){throw new TypeError("Failed to construct 'Promise': Please use the 'new' operator, this object constructor cannot be called as a function.")}function F(t){this._id=ut++,this._state=void 0,this._result=void 0,this._subscribers=[],m!==t&&(e(t)||P(),this instanceof F||z(),Y(this,t))}function I(){var t;if("undefined"!=typeof global)t=global;else if("undefined"!=typeof self)t=self;else try{t=Function("return this")()}catch(e){throw new Error("polyfill failed because global object is unavailable in this environment")}var n=t.Promise;(!n||"[object Promise]"!==Object.prototype.toString.call(n.resolve())||n.cast)&&(t.Promise=lt)}var O;O=Array.isArray?Array.isArray:function(t){return"[object Array]"===Object.prototype.toString.call(t)};var T,W,D,H=O,q=0,k=({}.toString,function(t,e){G[q]=t,G[q+1]=e,q+=2,2===q&&(W?W(c):D())}),N="undefined"!=typeof window?window:void 0,U=N||{},Q=U.MutationObserver||U.WebKitMutationObserver,J="undefined"!=typeof process&&"[object process]"==={}.toString.call(process),K="undefined"!=typeof Uint8ClampedArray&&"undefined"!=typeof importScripts&&"undefined"!=typeof MessageChannel,G=new Array(1e3);D=J?i():Q?a():K?u():void 0===N&&"function"==typeof require?p():l();var V=void 0,$=1,tt=2,et=new S,nt=new S;M.prototype._validateInput=function(t){return H(t)},M.prototype._validationError=function(){return new Error("Array Methods must be provided an Array")},M.prototype._init=function(){this._result=new Array(this.length)};var rt=M;M.prototype._enumerate=function(){for(var t=this,e=t.length,n=t.promise,r=t._input,o=0;n._state===V&&e>o;o++)t._eachEntry(r[o],o)},M.prototype._eachEntry=function(t,e){var r=this,o=r._instanceConstructor;n(t)?t.constructor===o&&t._state!==V?(t._onerror=null,r._settledAt(t._state,e,t._result)):r._willSettleAt(o.resolve(t),e):(r._remaining--,r._result[e]=t)},M.prototype._settledAt=function(t,e,n){var r=this,o=r.promise;o._state===V&&(r._remaining--,t===tt?C(o,n):r._result[e]=n),0===r._remaining&&b(o,r._result)},M.prototype._willSettleAt=function(t,e){var n=this;E(t,void 0,function(t){n._settledAt($,e,t)},function(t){n._settledAt(tt,e,t)})};var ot=B,it=Z,st=X,at=j,ut=0,lt=F;F.all=ot,F.race=it,F.resolve=st,F.reject=at,F._setScheduler=r,F._setAsap=o,F._asap=k,F.prototype={constructor:F,then:function(t,e){var n=this,r=n._state;if(r===$&&!t||r===tt&&!e)return this;var o=new this.constructor(m),i=n._result;if(r){var s=arguments[r-1];k(function(){R(r,o,s,i)})}else E(n,o,t,e);return o},"catch":function(t){return this.then(null,t)}};var ct=I,pt={Promise:lt,polyfill:ct};"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(function(){return pt}):"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=pt:"undefined"!=typeof this&&(this.ES6Promise=pt),ct()}.call(this);var M,B,Z,X=["Webkit","Moz","ms"],j=document.createElement("div").style;B=n("transform"),M=n("transformOrigin"),Z=n("userSelect");var P="translate3d",z=", 0px",F=function(t,e,n){this.x=parseFloat(t),this.y=parseFloat(e),this.scale=parseFloat(n)};F.parse=function(t){return t.style?F.parse(t.style[B]):t.indexOf("matrix")>-1||t.indexOf("none")>-1?F.fromMatrix(t):F.fromString(t)},F.fromMatrix=function(t){var e=t.substring(7).split(",");return e.length&&"none"!==t||(e=[1,0,0,1,0,0]),new F(parseInt(e[4],10),parseInt(e[5],10),parseFloat(e[0]))},F.fromString=function(t){var e=t.split(") "),n=e[0].substring(P.length+1).split(","),r=e.length>1?e[1].substring(6):1,o=n.length>1?n[0]:0,i=n.length>1?n[1]:0;return new F(o,i,r)},F.prototype.toString=function(){return P+"("+this.x+"px, "+this.y+"px"+z+") scale("+this.scale+")"};var I=function(t){if(!t||!t.style[M])return this.x=0,void(this.y=0);var e=t.style[M].split(" ");this.x=parseFloat(e[0]),this.y=parseFloat(e[1])};I.prototype.toString=function(){return this.x+"px "+this.y+"px"};var O=o(v,500);if(this.jQuery){var T=this.jQuery;T.fn.croppie=function(t){var e=typeof t;if("string"===e){var n=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1),r=T(this).data("croppie");return"get"===t?r.get():"result"===t?r.result.apply(r,n):this.each(function(){var e=T(this).data("croppie");if(e){var r=e[t];if(!T.isFunction(r))throw"Croppie "+t+" method not found";r.apply(e,n),"destroy"===t&&T(this).removeData("croppie")}})}return this.each(function(){var e=new Y(this,t);T(this).data("croppie",e)})}}Y.defaults={viewport:{width:100,height:100,type:"square"},boundary:{width:300,height:300},customClass:"",showZoom:!0,mouseWheelZoom:!0,update:function(){}},r(Y.prototype,{bind:function(t,e){return C.call(this,t,e)},get:function(){return L.call(this)},result:function(t){return S.call(this,t)},refresh:function(){return A.call(this)},destroy:function(){return R.call(this)}}),t.Croppie=window.Croppie=Y})};


croppieJs();


/*************************
 * acrCroppie
 * Allen Royston
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Updated 4/12/2016
 *************************/
 angular.module('ngCroppie', []).directive('ngCroppie', [
   function ($compile, $window) {
     return {
         restrict: 'AE',
         scope:{
           src: '=',
           viewport: '=',
           boundry: '=',
           type: '@',
           zoom: '@',
           mousezoom: '@',
           responsive: '@',
           update: '=',
           metric: '@',
           ngModel: '='
         },
         link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

           // defaults
           if(scope.viewport == undefined){
             scope.viewport = {w: null, h: null}
           }

           if(scope.boundry == undefined){
             scope.boundry = {w: null, h: null}
           }

           // catches
           scope.viewport.w = (scope.viewport.w != undefined) ? scope.viewport.w : 300;
           scope.viewport.h = (scope.viewport.h != undefined) ? scope.viewport.h : 300;
           scope.boundry.w = (scope.boundry.w != undefined) ? scope.boundry.w : 400;
           scope.boundry.h = (scope.boundry.h != undefined) ? scope.boundry.h : 400;

           // viewport cannot be larger than the boundaries
           if(scope.viewport.w > scope.boundry.w){ scope.viewport.w = scope.boundry.w }
           if(scope.viewport.h > scope.boundry.h){ scope.viewport.h = scope.boundry.h }

           // convert string to Boolean
           var zoom = (scope.zoom === "true"),
               mouseZoom = (scope.mousezoom === "true");

           // define options
           var options =  {
               viewport: {
                 width: scope.viewport.w,
                 height: scope.viewport.h,
                 type: scope.type || 'square'
               },
               boundary: {
                 width: scope.boundry.w,
                 height: scope.boundry.h
               },
               metric: scope.metric,
               showZoom: zoom,
               mouseWheelZoom: mouseZoom,
           }

           function init(){


                 if (scope.update != undefined){
                   options.update = scope.update
                 }

                 console.log('scope: ', scope)

                 // create new croppie and settime for updates
                 var c = new Croppie(elem[0], options);
                 var intervalID = window.setInterval(function(){
                   c.result('canvas').then(function(img){
                     scope.$apply(function(){
                       scope.ngModel = img
                     })
                   })
                 }, 250);

                 console.log('ccc : ', c)

                 scope.$on("$destroy",
                     function( event ) {
                         clearInterval(intervalID);
                         $(window).off('resize', function(){
                           responsive()});
                     }
                 );

                 // respond to changes in src
                 scope.$watch('src', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                     if(scope.src != undefined){
                           c.bind(scope.src);
                           c.result('canvas').then(function(img){
                             scope.$apply(function(){
                               scope.ngModel = img
                             })
                           })
                     }
               })

               };



               if(scope.responsive === 'true'){


                 function responsive(){
                 console.log('responsive')
                 // defaults
                 if(scope.viewport == undefined){
                   scope.viewport = {w: null, h: null}
                 }

                 if(scope.boundry == undefined){
                   scope.boundry = {w: null, h: null}
                 }

                 // convert string to Boolean
                 var zoom = (scope.zoom === "true"),
                     mouseZoom = (scope.mousezoom === "true");

                scope.width = $('.modal-md form').width()
                scope.height =  scope.width * .264;

                console.log('width : ', scope.width);

                 // define options
                  options =  {
                     viewport: {
                       width: scope.width,
                       height: scope.height,
                       type: scope.type || 'square'
                     },
                     boundary: {
                       width: scope.width,
                       height: scope.height
                     },
                     metric: scope.metric,
                     showZoom: zoom,
                     mouseWheelZoom: mouseZoom,
                 }


                 init();
               };

               responsive();

               $(window).on('resize', function(){
                 scope.$digest(function(){
                   delete scope.$$watchers[0];
                          scope.$$watchersCount = scope.$$watchers.length;
                 });
                 responsive();
                 clearInterval();
                 console.log('ccc : ', c)

               });


               }
               else{
                  init();
               }



         }

     };
   }
 ]);
```

Comment: do you have a plnkr of this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to can put all the link part of your directive in a function along with the variables you need to reinitiate and put them in a function and invoke that function on `window.resize` event, let me show you

```
 angular.module('ngCroppie',[]).directive('ngCroppie','$document','$log', [
    function ($compile) {
     return {
        restrict: 'AE',
         scope:{
           src: '=',
           viewport: '=',
           boundry: '=',
           type: '@',
           zoom: '@',
           mousezoom: '@',
           update: '=',
           ngModel: '='
         },
         link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

         function init()={
           // defaults
                if(scope.viewport == undefined){
                  scope.viewport = {w: null, h: null}
                }

                if(scope.boundry == undefined){
                  scope.boundry = {w: null, h: null}
                }

                // catches
                scope.viewport.w = (scope.viewport.w != undefined) ? scope.viewport.w : 300;
                scope.viewport.h = (scope.viewport.h != undefined) ? scope.viewport.h : 300;
                scope.boundry.w = (scope.boundry.w != undefined) ? scope.boundry.w : 400;
                scope.boundry.h = (scope.boundry.h != undefined) ? scope.boundry.h : 400;

                // viewport cannot be larger than the boundaries
                if(scope.viewport.w > scope.boundry.w){ scope.viewport.w = scope.boundry.w }
                if(scope.viewport.h > scope.boundry.h){ scope.viewport.h = scope.boundry.h }

                // convert string to Boolean
                var zoom = (scope.zoom === "true"),
                    mouseZoom = (scope.mousezoom === "true");

                // define options
                var options =  {
                    viewport: {
                      width: scope.viewport.w,
                      height: scope.viewport.h,
                      type: scope.type || 'square'
                    },
                    boundary: {
                      width: scope.boundry.w,
                      height: scope.boundry.h
                    },
                    showZoom: zoom,
                    mouseWheelZoom: mouseZoom,
                }

                if (scope.update != undefined){
                  options.update = scope.update
                }

                // create new croppie and settime for updates
                var c = new Croppie(elem[0], options);
            }

            init();

         //window resizing event

            $document.bind('click', function(event) {
                $log.info(event);
                 init()://intiating the variables again

            });


                var intervalID = window.setInterval(function(){
                  c.result('canvas').then(function(img){
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                      scope.ngModel = img
                    })
                  })
                }, 250);

                scope.$on("$destroy",
                    function( event ) {
                        clearInterval(intervalID);
                    }
                );

                // respond to changes in src
                scope.$watch('src', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    if(scope.src != undefined){
                          c.bind(scope.src);
                          c.result('canvas').then(function(img){
                            scope.$apply(function(){
                              scope.ngModel = img
                            })
                          })
                    }
              })


        }

    };
  }
]);
```

Try it out!

PS: unbind the resize event when you destroy the scope of directive, that can be done pretty much easily i guess

Comment: do I just need to call scope.$destroy() at the beginning of the resize event?

Comment: not really as you are not practically destroying the scope, you are just kind of programmatically re-initiating it, there is a difference

Comment: can you review my update above. I can't figure out how to delete the initial instance of the photo.

Comment: i guess it is happening because you are putting `scope.$watch('src', function(newValue, oldValue) `, inside function and it gets repeated for every instance of resize, just put the variables inside init, put the events outside of it, events will get repeated and get uncontrollable

Answer (score 0):

Did you try listening to the resize event in the link function?

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.doSomething = function() {

      //example of accessing element's attribute
      var width = $(element).width();
    };
    $window.addEventListener("resize", scope.doSomenthing);
  }
```